# Rails: PATCH request not entering controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that looks something like this:

```rb
<%=
  form_with(
    model: @my_model,
    url: my_model_path(@my_model),
    local: true
  ) do |f|
%>
  ...
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My route looks like this:

```rb
resources :my_models
```

My controller looks like this:

```rb
class MyModelsController
  ...
  def update
    klsdjfkdls
  end
end
```

When I hit the submit button, I can see the following in my logs:

```
Started PATCH "/my_models/1" for ::1 at 2021-03-14 12:43:00 -0400
Processing by MyModelsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: { [REDACTED] }
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/my_models/1
Completed 302 Found in 3ms
```

For some reason, the request never goes into the method, as it should complain that `klsdjfkdls` is not a method/variable/anything valid. It clearly needs to know about the `update` method because if I remove it, I get the following error:

```
Started PATCH "/my_models/1" for ::1 at 2021-03-14 12:42:33 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'update' could not be found for MyModelsController)
```

I'm at a loss as to why this does not work. I have the same set up with `my_other_model`, which works just fine.

Comment: @spickermann no, the method is not private

Comment: Do you have a `before_action` defined in that controller or in the ApplicationController that might cause the redirect?

Comment: @spickermann, good thought - I have a `before_action` but it's set for `only: :show` at the moment.

Comment: @spickermann, aha, I see something in an `include` that would call the redirect. Thank you!

Comment: @emilytrabert You should post your own answer or delete the question.